# Is there a shortcut to move items between your inventory and the crafting table?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

Is there a quick way to move items from your inventory onto the crafting table, just as you can move items between the inventory and an open chest with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>?

Comment: Crafting tends to also require specific layouts.  How would a system like this know where to put the items without giving away the layout?

Comment: This could be quite useful for crafting blocks, such as redstone blocks, coal blocks, and hay bales.

Comment: ******No.******

Comment: you can click drag (if it's mostly the same items in the recipe), or use NEI's shift clicking the "?" square

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Check out the new answer. It's not a lie! ;)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Wow, I did not know that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Items can be moved rapidly from your hotbar to the crafting table quickly by pressing the corresponding number while hovering your cursor over the desired destination slot in the crafting grid.

This is most useful when crafting a lot of something that takes only one ingredient.

1. craft a few of the destination items the "slow" way and use those items to reserve slots for that item in your inventory.  At this point your inventory should be totally full, with some of the ingredient in slots 1 and 2 of your hotbar.
2. Arrange for a large amount of the ingredient to be on the ground at your feet.  This can be done by breaking a chest full of only the ingredient.
3. open the crafting grid, move your cursor to the desired slot in the grid and press 1 and 2 to move the items into the grid.  As you do this, more items will be picked up off the ground to replace them.
4. Shift click the crafted item into your inventory into the slots you reserved for it in step 1.
5. repeat steps 3 and 4 until no more items are on the ground.

[Here's a video by jl2579](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlyF9MgA5Us) demonstrating the technique

Comment: Tested in vanilla: confirmed! Nice hidden feature! Have a +1.

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to quickly move items into the crafting table.
As TokenMacGuy said, you can do this by hovering your mouse over the slot in the crafting table and pressing the corresponding number for the one in your hotbar.

Here's list of controls to quickly move around items in your inventory that I know of:

Double <kbd>Left Click</kbd> - sort loose items into one stack.
Hold and Drag <kbd>Left Click</kbd> - split a stack evenly into each inventory slot.
Hold and Drag <kbd>Right Click</kbd> - place one item from a stack into each inventory slot.
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> - move all the items from the stack into the hotbar/out of the hotbar. Put items in/out of chests, furnaces, enchanting tables, anvils, brewing stands, beacons, dispensers, droppers and hoppers. It will also put on and take off armour.
<kbd>num 1-9</kbd> - if you hold your mouse over an item and press a number it will put that item into the number in the hotbar.

EDIT: Turns out there is a way to move items into the crafting table but I will leave this answer. Found out how to do those keyboard things.

Comment: See [this answer that contradicts this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/128573/4163). I thought it must be a mod, but I just tested it in vanilla and it works. Just leaving you a note here in case you want to delete or update to avoid downvotes. Also, now you can enjoy this hidden feature. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks for notifying me! I should've actually tried to experiment with the crafting table before coming up with my answer. My bad.

Comment: I never would have guessed that method myself, so I don't think you bear any guilt. :)

Comment: Another useful one is hold a stack and shift + double left click on another stack of the same material to transfer all stacks of that material to/from inventory. Great for (un)loading by the chestfull.

Answer (score -1):

If you hold left-shift and click, it should put the item straight into the inventory chest.

Comment: This answer does not add anything new.

Answer (score -2):

The item either needs to be in the inventory or the hot bar (I don't quite remember). Hold shift then "W" and click on the item. Works for me, not sure if a mod or not.

Comment: Tested in vanilla: doesn't work. It must be one of your mods.